# Firebase dynamic links Expo dev

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-dynamic-links

Im trying to implement Firebase dynamic links into my react native app. I'm using expo dev since it clearly states [here](https://rnfirebase.io/#expo) that Expo Go does not support firebase.
However when running `const link = await dynamicLinks().getInitialLink()` I keep getting `Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp()`
Where am I supposed to initialize it? It's a bit hard to find documentation or any mention of initializing firebase for a react native app, all I can find is for a web and I'm missing a lot of the config params.

I did setup my app.json according to the [these docs](https://rnfirebase.io/#managed-workflow)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my firebase config was missing non optional items, once I filled them out I initialized my app like so

```
  if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  } else {
    firebase.app(); // if already initialized, use that one
  }
```

and the config min required is

```
export const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "my key",
    projectId: "my project id",
    appId:"my app id",
    databaseURL:"my db url",
    messagingSenderId:"my id",
    storageBucket:"bucket"
};
```